# Gradle project sync failed AndroidStudio 4.2

Tags: gradle

I'm new here. I thought I wanted to learn how to make an app using Android Studio, but I have stumbled upon this error where I haven't even done anything yet. I have tried most of the solutions I could find but to no avail. Tq to those who are willing to help out a newbie here

Here's the log : https://drive.google.com/file/d/159r7fccIByK9E2lANcE8HY0NKY-Kh5WS/view?usp=sharing

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqf4M.png)

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vJxU.png)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to resolve all the problems you have in your layout. You could open the xml file in 'code version' and do whatever android studio say you should do.
Then, you should try to sync your project again (File > Sync Project with Gradle Files). Also, you could just make File > Invalidate Caches /Restart or just restart android studio.

Hope I solved your problem :)